# Set order of stacked area chart by values in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, ggplotly

could you tell me how to order stacked charts from top to down by sales in 2020? For instance, in 2020 sales were the highest in the 9nth category, so I want to be in this category at the top and so on. In addition, I need to round up years (2012.5 to 2012) I set them as Integer but does not work.
used code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=Sale, fill=group)) + 
    geom_area()
```

[image]

Comment: As I'm not sure what's the issue I deleted my answer. Maybe you could provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Could you provide some code to reproduce what you want?

Comment: For me to know, you want to round '.5' values to the nearest lowest value, as you said '2012.5' to '2012' but what if you have '2012.6' it's gonna be '2012' or '2013'?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `2012.5` or higher (example: `2012.9`) to `2012` you just simple use the `trunc()` function this will cut the decimal and keep you the entire value, in this sense you'll only have the `2012`

```
#try:
trunc(2.2)
trunc(2.5)
trunc(2.99999999)
```

You can use `floor()` as well:

```
#try
floor(2.2)
floor(2.5)
floor(2.999999999)
```

so insted of using `int()` for `years` try one of this built-in functions.